# Else if isn't working

Tags: java

This should put word yup to every second character, yap to every fifth and both yup yap to every tenth. It does put only yup to every second character.

I can't figure out what's the problem. Thank you for your help.

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)    {

        if( i % 2 != 0)   {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yup");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if( i + 1 % 5 == 0)    {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yap");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if( i + 1 % 10 == 0)   {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yup yap");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have u tried debugging your application? Set a breakpoint in the beginning and step through the code to see what it does.

Comment: Care of your operator priority `( (i + 1) % 5 == 0)`

Comment: What unexpected happens?

Comment: Even with `(i + 1) % 10 == 0`, what values of `i` would match that? 9, 19, 29, 39, .... All odd values, and odd values are caught by the `i % 2 != 0` in the first `if`, so it'll **never** be true.

Comment: *"Else if isn't working"* ... it's a little arrogant, I think, to presuppose that a convention, which has continually been in use for over a decade, must be faulty because it isn't behaving the way you expect.  I would say that it is much more likely that *"Else If is working just as expected"* and that your application of it is faulty.

Comment: @scottb *"for over a decade"* LOL It's been in use for a heck of a lot longer than that, e.g. FORTRAN 77.

Answer (score 3):

Put () in your `else if` operations. Mod (%) has precedence over sum, that's why it's not working.

```
else if( (i + 1) % 5  == 0)
```

and

```
else if(( i + 1) % 10 == 0)
```

Comment: `( i + 1) % 10 == 0` still won't work. It'll be hidden by both `i % 2 != 0` *and* `(i + 1) % 5  == 0`.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. Besides the operator priority issue, this is another problem.

Answer (score 3):

Modulo 5 "hides" modulo "10". You must rethink your algorithm. Any number that is multiple of 10, is also multiple of 5.

Comment: `i % 2 != 0` hides `(i + 1) % 10 == 0`, so `(i + 1) % 5 == 0` will never get an opportunity to hide it. *(assuming parens are added as suggested by [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41211354/5221149))*.

Comment: Changed it a little bit and now it works, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the if-else statements and put `i + 1` in braces:

```
    if((i + 1) % 10 == 0)   {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yup yup");
        System.out.println();
    }
    else if((i + 1) % 5 == 0)    {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yap");
        System.out.println();
    }
    else if(i % 2 != 0)   {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " yup");
        System.out.println();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
    }
```

If `(i + 1) % 10` is zero, then `(i + 1) % 5` is zero, too.

Comment: `i + 1 % 10 == 0` is only true for `i = -1`, i.e. it's never true here.

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of operator priority because Mod (%) has precedence over sum (+).

```
else if( i + 1 % 5 == 0)
```

This `else if` is not working like it is supposed to, because Mod (%) will execute prior to sum (+). That is why you have to change the code to make it work:

```
else if( (i + 1) % 5 == 0)
```

Comment: This answer needs elaboration. "Please take care" doesn't clarify exactly what problems could be encountered because of the precedence.

Comment: else if( i + 1 % 5  == 0)
This else if is not functioning well as it suppose to because Mod (%) will execute prior to sum (+). 
That is why we have to change the code a bit to make it workable as
else if( (i + 1) % 5  == 0)